# Wordpress Ajax always returns 0 despite success in Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to read from Wordpress's `wp_users` table (via Ajax request), and view it in the page. I need your help let me know what I have done wrong to successfully print the root email address by using Ajax.

My JavaScript ajax call is:

```
function ajaxTest ()
        {
            // Creating the URL that Ajax must refer to.
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

            // Do Ajax call.
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: "POST",
                data: { action: "wp_ajax_tester" },
                complete: function( xhr, status ){
                    console.log("Request completion status: " + status);
                },
                success: function (response){
                    console.log("result: " + response);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log("error: " + errorThrown);
                } 
            });
        }
```

And in the `functions.php` I have created the code below:

```
function app_tester()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT user_email FROM wp_users WHERE user='root'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
    echo json_encode($results;);
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_tester', 'app_tester');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tester', 'app_tester');
```

I want to print out the root email address, but this is what printed in the browser's console:

```
result: 0
Request completion status: Successful
```

I am using Wordpress's own jQuery by putting the line below in the files head section:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you run that query on your database directly to ensure it actually returns some results?

Comment: Yes sir and it turned out there is no `user` field there avaiable. just the smallest mistake and it just ruined my day. The field is called `user_login` and I think I need some negative points here. Thank you very much for giving me the hint to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for Ajax, please remove wp_ajax_ from action

Example code

```
function ajaxTest ()
    {
        // Creating the URL that Ajax must refer to.
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

        // Do Ajax call.
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: "tester" },
            complete: function( xhr, status ){
                console.log("Request completion status: " + status);
            },
            success: function (response){
                console.log("result: " + response);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log("error: " + errorThrown);
            } 
        });
    }
```